# Does OWASP recommend to include a CSRF-token in a header or to use it as a parameter (in a State-scenario)?

Tags: csrf, token, owasp, ajax

The CSRF Cheat Sheet by OWASP, concerning (Anti-)CSRF-tokens is quite confusing.
For a State(ful)-scenario (the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#synchronizer-token-pattern)), they write:

> ... for AJAX calls it is recommended to add in parameter than in header.
>   If you need to add it to header, it is better to make sure that the
>   token header is not being logged at your server.

In the next paragraph, they write:

> Inserting the CSRF token in the HTTP request header via JavaScript is
>   considered more secure than adding the token in the hidden field form
>   parameter. In this situation, even if the CSRF token is weak,
>   predictable or leaked but still an attacker cannot forge the POST
>   request directly by setting the custom request header through
>   XMLHttpRequest.

Based on [an answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/58308/208838) to another question on StackExchange, I came to the conclusion that sending it as a header has one disadvantage: different frameworks expect the token in different headers (`X-Requested-By`, `X-Requested-With`, `X-XSRF-TOKEN`, `X-CSRF-TOKEN`). However, I still cannot understand which is more secure? The token as a parameter-value or as a header (for Ajax-calls)? And why?

Comment: Can I understand your question as "Why does OWASP argue for headers in one case and against headers in another case?"

Comment: 1) Yes en 2) which one is more secure?