# Is CSRF attack possible with Custom X- Header?

Tags: csrf

In sum, if I am able to add a custom header to a request, that allows the disabling of CSRF check, will the endpoint be vulnerable to CSRF Attack ?

I'm bit lost.A custom header is such `X-SKIP-CSRF: YES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here's a whole conversation about custom headers here.

[CSRF protection with custom headers (and without validating token)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/csrf-protection-with-custom-headers-and-without-validating-token)

Hope it helps.